# How to Authenticate Angular 2 with Firebase API using Auth0

Tags: angular, curl, firebase, auth0

I read [an article](https://auth0.com/authenticate/angular2/firebase) about how to authenticate angular app with firebase API using Auth0.

I followed the step described in here, however I would not be able to 
call the Delegation endpoint from Auth0 to get a token for Firebase API using curl command.

How do I do below:

```
curl --data \
"client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&\
 &grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer\
 &refresh_token=\
 &scope=open_id\
 &api_type=firebase"\
 https://YOUR_ACCOUNT.auth0.com/delegation
```

Comment: What do you mean how do you?  As written I would say run that command at a command prompt...

Comment: My knowledge regarding Linux related command is minimal..  should I install something ? on angular project ??

Comment: Maybe: https://www.jasom.net/how-to-install-curl-command-manually-on-debian-linux will help?

Comment: Thank you Joshua. I am doing Imac ...  The below is helpful ??? Press Command+Space and type Terminal and press enter/return key.
Run in Terminal app:
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
and press enter/return key. Wait for the command to finish.
Run:
brew install curl
Done! You can now use curl.